# fixing python-mode automatic line-breaks in the output?

Tags: python

I'm using emacs python mode to evaluate python (3.6) code and expressions. The mode (or emacs) seems to automatically break output lines at a certain length, even though my screen is wide enough to hold the whole thing. Below is an example:

```
>>> dfv
sector       treasury  hardware  theater  telecom  brewery  highways  cars  \
sector                                                                       
treasury          0.1       0.0        0        0      0.0       0.0   0.0   
hardware          0.0      19.0       -2        4      1.0       1.0   1.0   
theater           0.0      -2.0       28        1      2.0       1.0   1.0   
telecom           0.0       4.0        1       22      0.0       1.0   2.0   
brewery           0.0       1.0        2        0      4.0      -1.5  -2.0   
highways          0.0       1.0        1        1     -1.5       3.5   2.0   
cars              0.0       1.0        1        2     -2.0       2.0   5.0   
bank              0.0       0.5        0        0     -1.0       0.5   0.5   
software          0.0      10.0       -2        3      1.0       1.0   1.0   
electronics       0.0       5.0       -1        4      1.0       1.5   2.5   

sector       bank  software  electronics  
sector                                    
treasury      0.0       0.0          0.0  
hardware      0.5      10.0          5.0  
theater       0.0      -2.0         -1.0  
telecom       0.0       3.0          4.0  
brewery      -1.0       1.0          1.0  
highways      0.5       1.0          1.5  
cars          0.5       1.0          2.5  
bank          1.0       0.5          0.5  
software      0.5      25.0          8.0  
electronics   0.5       8.0         16.0
```

Is there a way to let python-mode to use the full window width or turn off the automatic line-break gracefully?

I am using Emacs 25.x GUI, Ubuntu 18.04.